# nix-shell -p llvmPackages_8.stdenv doesn't have clang8 set in env

Tags: c++, clang, darwin, nix-shell

I'm trying to build a C++ project that requires a rather old version of clang, namely version 8.
That project doesn't have any default.nix or shell.nix.

I tried:

```bash
> nix-shell -p llvmPackages_8.stdenv
[nix-shell:~/git/the-project]$ clang --version
clang version 11.1.0
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /nix/store/s759kzdnl4p740wj1965bcygwn88n4xx-clang-11.1.0/bin
```

As you can see the clang version is not the one I expected it to be.
I also tried

- nix-shell -p llvmPackages_8.stdenv -p clang_8
- nix-shell -p clangStdenv
- nix-shell -p clangStdenv -p clang_8

Am I getting something wrong with nix-shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out my self. This is how I overcame the problem. I created a shell.nix in the repo with this content:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
llvmPackages.libcxxStdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "env";
  nativeBuildInputs = [ clang-tools ];
  buildInputs = [ cmake openssl_1_1 python ] ++ lib.optionals libcxxStdenv.isDarwin (with darwin.apple_sdk.frameworks; [
    Cocoa
    CoreServices
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't get clang-tidy work properly, until I added clang-tools to nativeBuildInputs.